# A bug of UIScrollView contentOffset?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I set the property `isPagingEnabled` of a scrollView to `true`, like this:

```
let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width * 2, height: 0)
scrollView.delegate = self
scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

and delegate method:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print(scrollView.contentOffset.x)
}
```

When scrolling the view to the boundary, the console print, as shown in:

[image]

and

[image]

The values in the red box should not be printed out, right?

But, if setting `isPagingEnabled` to `false`, the console print is normal.  Is this a bug of `UIScrollView`?

Comment: I think those values get printed due to the "bounce" effect. If you disable bounce, then they won't get printed.

Answer (score 1):

Your Content offset is showing wrong because your are using content size in viewdidload use content size in this method than print your content off set

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
 {
  scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width * 2, height: 0)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i Know, Its working correctly, when you are setting **contentSize** to your **scrollview**, that will respond to their **delegate** at first time itself.

**func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)**

Whenever user try to scroll or drag, the above delegate will call recursively, Here your contentSize of width is double of Your view bounds width(so there is two page, the **contentOffset.x** will start with 0 and current position of scroll, if it is in second page, that will give your view **width * n** ), and you set **isPagingEnabled** to **true**.

Check this https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview/1619404-contentoffset

The default value is **CGPoint​Zero**.

Actually contentOffset will tell you that current scroll position.

Comment: No, it is not what I want, I re-edited the question, like the pictures shown, I think the values in the red box is redundant. They should not be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever `UIScrollView` make scrolling, this method `scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` invokes. Any of the direction if you scroll you will get these types of output.

However if you want like a pagination approach then instead of this method you can use:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
        print("pageNumber = \(pageNumber)")

    }
```

By this method you will get the exact page no of `UIScrollView`.

Comment: No, you didn't understand what I meant.

Comment: I mean that the printed value of `contentOffset` is incorrect, like the pictures shown.

Answer (score 0):

Please use frame instead of bounds .

The bounds of an UIView is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y) and size (width,height) relative to its own coordinate system (0,0).The frame of an UIView is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y) and size (width,height) relative to the superview it is contained within.

```
 let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.frame.size)
 scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width * 2, 
 height: 0)
 scrollView.delegate = self
 scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
 view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not what I want, I re-edited the question, you can look back at it.